# PHP вопрос про конкатенацию

Tags: php

Есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
return '<div class="chatboard">
<div id="dialogs"><div class="title">'.lastdialogs.'</div><ul>'.$dialogs.'</ul></div>
<div id="msgboard"><div class="title">'.messages.'</div>'.$msg.'</div>
<form id="msgform" onsubmit="sendchat('.$this->types['chat'].'); return false;">
<textarea id="msgtextarea" placeholder="'.yourmessage.'" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
<button class="btndefault" id="msgbtn">'.send.'</button>
</form>
</div>';
```

Возможно ли сделать так:

```
return '<div class="chatboard">
<div id="dialogs"><div class="title">'.lastdialogs.'</div><ul>'.$dialogs.'</ul></div>
<div id="msgboard"><div class="title">'.messages.'</div>'.$msg.'</div>

здесь проверка, если определенная переменная равна значению, то выводим этот отрезок кода
<form id="msgform" onsubmit="sendchat('.$this->types['chat'].'); return false;">
<textarea id="msgtextarea" placeholder="'.yourmessage.'" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
<button class="btndefault" id="msgbtn">'.send.'</button>
</form>
если переменная не равна, то этот фрагмент не будет возвращен

</div>';
```

Comment: Старайтесь не мешать `html`  со скрипт-кодом. - используйте `html` в качестве буфера вывода - отправляйте в `html` только переменные и функции которые уже возвращают данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1 - присвоить переменной:

```
$code = '<div class="chatboard">
<div id="dialogs"><div class="title">'.lastdialogs.'</div><ul>'.$dialogs.'</ul></div>
<div id="msgboard"><div class="title">'.messages.'</div>'.$msg.'</div>';
if(условие)
{
    $code .= '<form id="msgform" onsubmit="sendchat('.$this->types['chat'].'); return false;">
    <textarea id="msgtextarea" placeholder="'.yourmessage.'" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
    <button class="btndefault" id="msgbtn">'.send.'</button>
    </form>';
}
$code .= '</div>';
return $code;
```

Вариант 2 - пишем в том же стиле(в общей куче):

```
return '<div class="chatboard">
<div id="dialogs"><div class="title">'.lastdialogs.'</div><ul>'.$dialogs.'</ul></div>
<div id="msgboard"><div class="title">'.messages.'</div>'.$msg.'</div>
'.((условие) ? '<form id="msgform" onsubmit="sendchat('.$this->types['chat'].'); return false;">
<textarea id="msgtextarea" placeholder="'.yourmessage.'" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
<button class="btndefault" id="msgbtn">'.send.'</button>
</form>' : '').
</div>';
```